# Rails client order history in one query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, associations, aggregate-functions

I'm attempting to generate a customer profile page. The page includes customer order history, most recent orders, and their historical totals. I've been running sum, count, and average on Customer.where_completed but that's touching that database three times. I feel there has to be a better way?

```
@customers_total_spent = @customer.orders.where_completed.sum(:sale)
@customers_average_per_order = @customer.orders.where_completed.average(:sale)
@customers_total_orders = @customer.orders.where_completed.count(:sale)
```

### Customers

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
end
```

### Orders

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customer
    scope :completed,-> { where.not(completed_at: nil) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
orders_completed = @customer.orders.where_completed.pluck("sum(sale), avg(sale), count(sale)").flatten
@customers_total_spent = orders_completed[0]
@customers_average_per_order = orders_completed[1]
@customers_total_orders = orders_completed[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@qry = @customer.orders.where_completed.select("sum(sale) as sum, avg(sale) as avg, count(sale) as count").first
@customers_total_spent = @qry.sum
@customers_average_per_order = @qry.avg
@customers_total_orders = @qry.count
```